# Eclipse: Exclude (test) folder from distribution (jar)

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, executable-jar

Assuming I have a simple project structure that separates application sources from test sources like:

> Project 
>     |-src
>      |-test

and I want to exclude `test` folder from executable jar using Eclipse.

Eclipse let's you select which folders to include when creating a jar. It does not let you do it when creating an **executable jar**.
Searching for a solution I found suggestions to 

[manually edit the ant build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11702359/3992939)or [maven](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Excluding-packages-and-classes-from-jar-td106688.html),

 or [exclude test folders from classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11641680/3992939) 

or [moving test files to a separate project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16188557/3992939) 

or [edit the exported jar](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=198085&goto=633133&#msg_633133).

While all this may work, it is not what I am looking for: a simple way to configure Eclipse to do it.

(In Netbeans its quiet simple separating source package folders from test folders, see the following image)

[image]

Comment: TIP: no matter what IDE you choose, always configure your projects with Maven (or any Maven alternative). Please believe-me, creating template projects from specific IDE is the root a of a lot of evil around Java project. This "avoid test folder" is one of those.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. This folder structure is widely used and is not IDE specific. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540344/3992939)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the upcoming version Photon (4.8) of Eclipse [a source folder can be marked that it contains test code](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/M5/#jdt-test-sources). The *Runnable JAR file* export wizard excludes this test code.

You can [download the milestone 5 (M5) of the Eclipse 4.8 SDK here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.8M5-201801242000/) and [soon](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg15268.html) (probably Monday) also the [Photon M5 Eclipse IDE packages here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php).

Comment: Nice. That may be exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to follow the [maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and setup your project as a *maven* or *greadle* project.

With a plain eclipse Java project you create a new folder for your tests in the projects root (e.g.: `test`) rightclick on it and select "add to build path".

Comment: I prefer the structure I use, because this way you don't need to change class modifiers (i.e make it public) just for testing. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540344/3992939). A separate project can be an alternative to what I use now. Anyway this is an interesting discussion but it does not answer the question.